# Pandas group by 2 columns, apply function, select max value and return index values

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the operation I am trying to do:

```
    ID    SUB_ID    AMOUNT

1   101     1        50
2   101     1        -10
3   101     1        -20
4   101     2        30
5   101     2        20
6   102     3        10
7   102     3        -10
8   102     4        10
9   102     4        10
```

We want to group by `ID` and `SUB_ID`, and then take the sum of the absolute value of `AMOUNT`. Then order this summed up column within `ID` groups and return the `SUB_ID` values of the maximum value.

We can get the summation by:

```
df1 = (df
    .groupby(['ID','SUB_ID'])
    .apply(lambda x: np.sum(np.absolute(x['AMOUNT']))))
)
```

This will return a Series with MultiIndex

```
 ID    SUB_ID    

 101     1        80
         2        50
 102     3        20
         4        20
```

From here I would like to return [1,3] ([1,4] is also accepted as the two values in the 102 group are the same, but we want to return only one value per group!)

Obviously we can loop and pick the max but I am trying to find out the most efficient way possible. This operation will be applied to millions of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way. As your dataset is large, I strongly recommend you avoid `lambda` functions since these are not applied in a vectorised fashion.

```
res = df.assign(AMOUNT=df['AMOUNT'].abs())\
        .groupby(['ID', 'SUB_ID'], as_index=False).sum()\
        .sort_values('AMOUNT', ascending=False)\
        .groupby('ID').head(1)
```

---

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[101, 1, 50], [101, 1, -10], [101, 1, -20], [101, 2, 30],
                   [101, 2, 20], [102, 3, 10], [102, 3, -10], [102, 4, 10], [102, 4, 10]],
                  columns=['ID', 'SUB_ID', 'AMOUNT'])

res = df.assign(AMOUNT=df['AMOUNT'].abs())\
        .groupby(['ID', 'SUB_ID'], as_index=False).sum()\
        .sort_values('AMOUNT', ascending=False)\
        .groupby('ID').head(1)

print(res)

    ID  SUB_ID  AMOUNT
0  101       1      80
2  102       3      20
```

Comment: Thanks man. Had to do one change though. Needed to change second line to:
`.groupby(['ID', 'SUB_ID'], as_index=False)['AMOUNT'].sum()\`
Else it would be a key error

Comment: @user4505419, Hmm, I don't see this problem on pandas v0.20.3. I've included the complete code.

Comment: Yes the example I gave works. Turns out dtype of the AMOUNT column is "object" in the real data for some reason and if I do not specifically put ['AMOUNT'] there it does not sum up that column.

Comment: Ok, you should really convert to numeric beforehand.. `df['AMOUNT'] = pd.to_numeric(df['AMOUNT'])` or `df['AMOUNT'] = df['AMOUNT'].astype(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `nlargest`:

```
df1.groupby('ID').nlargest(1).index.get_level_values(level='SUB_ID').tolist()

# [1, 3]
```